# Rails server start/stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

To run the **Rails server**, I use `$rails server`. It says 'To stop, click `Ctrl+c`'.
I use `Putty`.

The questions are:

1. Should I keep the terminal open always? Because if the server stops, my web page wouldn't work. With Apache I just used commands apachectl start/stop.
2. What if I want to use a command? Should I stop the server, use command, and run again? Because in the same terminal I can't do enything if the server run.

Comment: Well,you can start it in background or use some server like passenger, it's easy to use and convenient.

Comment: How to start it in background? Like with Apache

Comment: To start rails server with apache as reverse proxy you need some application server to serve your ruby code. Check this link for guide how to set up it: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Comment: No, I use Puma server. I mean, how to run Puma in background, like we do it with apache

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can run it in background by writing

```
daemonize true
```

in your puma.rb file

To stop you need to find your running puma process

```
 ps aux | grep puma
```

then you need to kill the main process

```
 sudo kill -9 your process id
```

to start you need to type

```
 puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios updated my answer hope it resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it

Comment: If you have puma in a systemd service, then you don't need to use the kill command. Wild to use the kill command to shut down an application server.

Comment: Unfortunately `daemonize` has been removed in Puma 5.0. For details: [link](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/deployment.md#should-i-daemonize)

Answer (score 9):

You can start a daemonized server by adding `-d` to your command. For instance:

```
rails server -d
```

To stop the server, you can kill it based on its process id:

```
kill $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I keep the terminal open always? Because if the server stops, my web page wouldn't work. With Apache I just used commands apachectl start/stop.

Yes, you should keep it open because if you Ctrl C it will stop the server. Another option is to run it in the background but I'm not sure how to do that in Putty.

> What if I want to use a command? Should I stop the server, use command, and run again? Because in the same terminal I can't do enything if the server run.

Can you open another terminal window? If you have two terminal windows you can use one for running the server and another for other tasks.

Comment: Ok, let's say you've developed a project and uploaded to a hosting. Where would you keep the terminal open? It seems stupid, why in apache is not like that?

Comment: Hosting in development and production  are two very different scenarios. It usually easier to run in the  terminal in development but you need something more robust for production.

Comment: What, for example?